# Not able to upload image from the Android app to answer from my device gallery

Tags: bug, android-app

Today, I answered a question on android community, and at that time I was using my Android device and Stack Exchange Android App and I submitted my answer with image selected from my device gallery.

However, I found that my answer was uploaded without any image. So later on I tried to edit it from my laptop runs Windows 10 and used Firefox to browse Stack Overflow.com and got success so I found that this is an issue with the Android app.

I tested it clearly with my Android device app but no success. And for sure I can tell you that my device and Internet is okay since I am able to upload images from the same device to Facebook and Twitter using its gallery.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: Samsung
- Device Model: SM-J200G
- OS Version: 5.1.1 (J200GDDU1APE6)